# How to parse number in c#?

Tags: c#, parsing, numbers, integer

I want to parse a number with 11 characters.

For example; number is 12345678900

With parse it should be ; 1234 5678 900

How can I do this?

Comment: That's not what `parse` means.  Do you want to format a string, or do you want to get an `int`?

Comment: For parsing you should use `var number = long.Parse("12345678900");`, the other part is rather a formatted string.

Comment: An int has at most 10 characters :) What's wrong with long.TryParse? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, my english is little. I save this number as a varchar in database. I only want to split it like example.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example, you could use the following:

```
var numString = 12345678900.ToString();
var result1 = Convert.ToInt32(numString.Substring(0, 4)); //1234
var result2 = Convert.ToInt32(numString.Substring(4, 4)); //5678
var result3 = Convert.ToInt32(numString.Substring(8, 3)); //900
```

Comment: If you know it's only 4 chars why use Int32 and not Int16?

Comment: @EmrahŞentürk You're welcome, don't forget to mark answers as correct :)

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko just to be super-safe ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would probably work.

```
int number = 12345678900;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String nums = number.ToString();
char[] numsChar = nums.ToCharArray();

for(int x = 1; x < numsChar.length; x++){
   if(x%4==0)
    sb.Append(numsChar[x-1] + @" ");
   else
    sb.Append(numsChar[x-1]);
}

String parsedNumber = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: That's an awful solution and really ugly code. It really shouldn't be suggested to new people to write such code

Answer (score 1):

if you have the string with 11 chars which representing a number
so you can use something like this

```
string num = "12345678901";
num.ToString("0000 0000");
```

I am not sure but i think you want to show your number as phone number and easy to remember, so take a look at ToString method specs in MSDN

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a string containing numeric characters then you can use this:

```
String.Format("{0:(####) #### ###}", 12345678900); OR
String.Format("{0:(####) #### ###}", txtPhoneNumber.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean you want the result string "1234 5678 900":

```
int num = 12345678900;
string numString = num.toString();

string result = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}",numString.SubString(0,4),numString.SubString(4,4),numString.SubString(8,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
Value.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And then replace the dot and the comma with spaces. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
long numberlong = 12345678900;
string number = numberlong.ToString();
int first = Convert.ToInt32(number.Substring(0, 4));
int second = Convert.ToInt32(number.Substring(4, 4));
int third = Convert.ToInt32(number.Substring(8, 3));
label1.Text = first.ToString() + " " + second.ToString() + " " + third.ToString();
```